# Drupal PHP executing twice

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

After running a drush update on my drupal 7 site, the php code that I use to bring in user information for a form executes twice. This is a problem because I have created some functions in the php that get called so when it executes the PHP the second time it tries to re-declare the functions and I get errors like this:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare fooBar() (previously declared in [path_to_drupal7]/modules/php/php.module(80) : eval()'d code:3) in [path_to_drupal7]/modules/php/php.module(80) : eval()'d code on line 4
```

It doesn't matter what the function is called or what it does. In this example case this is the code:

```
<?php
function fooBar() {
    print "foo bar";
}

fooBar();
?>
```

It also doesn't seem to matter what content type the page is (I my case I need it to bring user information into a form).

Why is Drupal executing the PHP twice? And more importantly, how can I keep it from doing so?

EDIT:
Drupal seems to be executing the php once for the trimmed version and once for full version and once for the full version. This is what I expect when I preview the post. I don't really care about the preview version so I would be happy to get rid of it. Why is Drupal executing the code twice when I view the page? (why is it running it for the trimmed version when I'm actually viewing the page?)

Comment: What modules were updated?

Comment: It looks like the drupal core was updated from 7.22 to 7.23. The Views module was also updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something must be re-including/requiring the file containing this function or you have this function within a loop.  Find that, or, wrap it with [function_exists](https://www.php.net/function_exists).

```
<?php

if (!function_exists('fooBar')) {
    function fooBar() {
        print "foo bar";
    }
}

fooBar();
```

Comment: that works as a way to get things working for now but it doesn't really solve the problem. Drupal is still running the code twice, and that's really what I want to prevent. Also, the `fooBar()` needs to be moved inside the if statement otherwise it will get called twice as well.

Comment: @cjc, can you provide a little more information?  What modules are you using?  Where is this function being called?  What should this function do?

Comment: The code is being executed as the body of the page using PHP code. Turns out the the `fooBar()` doesn't need to be inside the if statement since the first execution is for the trimmed text and the second execution is for the full text.

Answer (score 0):

Like you said, the php you entered as input is being eval'd twice....once for the teaser, and once for the full body text.

**Best practice**: Don't define functions with eval.  It can get messy fast.

**Better practice**: eval = evil.  Don't use it.

In the time it takes to debug the problem, you could have written a very basic module that defines fooBar, then you can execute it from your PHP input field if you want.